# Is it possible to change DNS record of service on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

```
kubectl get svc -n test

NAME                               TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                       AGE
rmq-deneme-rabbitmq-ha             ClusterIP   10.43.34.100   <none>        15672/TCP,5672/TCP,4369/TCP   33h
rmq-deneme-rabbitmq-ha-discovery   ClusterIP   None           <none>        15672/TCP,5672/TCP,4369/TCP   33h
```

I want to change default record of service from

```
rmq-deneme-rabbitmq-ha.test.svc.cluster.local
```

to

```
rmq-deneme-rabbitmq-ha.{custom.domain}
```

I could not find any documentation to do this. Is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Kubernetes itself, but you might be able to configure [CoreDNS](https://coredns.io/) (the DNS service in your cluster) to map your custom domain to the default domain of the service.

See this page: [Custom DNS Entries For Kubernetes](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/).